# Using BackgroundWorker or Threading for high performance

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, backgroundworker

How can use BackgroundWorker or Threading for my code. I update TreeView (Winforms) and I call WCF service.

Any suggestions please. Kind regards.

Thanks in advance

```
AdministradorUILogging.TrazarDebug("PanelArbolFicheros. tslGuardarArbol_Click")
Dim listaFichero As New List(Of Fichero)

Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

Me.TreeViewGB1.SuspendUpdate()

For Each nodo As NodoArbol In TreeViewGB1.Nodes

ProcesarNodo(nodo, listaFichero)

Next

Me.TreeViewGB1.ResumeUpdate()

' Cambiamos el cursor , tener en cuena si hacerlo asincrono '

Try

Using bfll As New ComunBfll()

bfll.AltaManualListaFicheros(listaFichero)

Mensajes.InformacionGuardada()

End Using

Catch ex As WCF.ServicioBase.Contrato.Excepciones.NoExisteOperacionException

Mensajes.AdvertenciaErrores("No existe la operación")

Catch ex As WCF.ServicioBase.Contrato.Excepciones.NoExisteExpedienteException

Mensajes.AdvertenciaErrores("No existe el expediente")

Catch ex As WCF.ServicioBase.Contrato.Excepciones.ConsistenciaException

Mensajes.AdvertenciaErrores("Inconsistencia detectada al superar el máximo permitido de ficheros para un tipo documental")

Catch ex As Exception

AdministradorUILogging.TrazarError(Me.[GetType]().FullName & " -> " & System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name & "." & ex.Message)

ExcepcionesIUUtil.ProcesarExcepcionPresentacion(ex, Me.Container)

End Try

InicializarArbol()

Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.Arrow
```

Comment: Please, format your code, it hurts XD

Comment: agreed; indentation is your friend.

Comment: i believe there is a code tag on here just for code.

Answer (score 2):

Using a BackgroundWorker or **one** thread will not make your application go faster, but will just prevent your application from not responding.

If you only need one thread, just use a BackgroundWorker, that's what it's meant for.

**If** in this precise case, your **listaFichero** variable can be splitted into smaller lists and processed in parallel, **and** the bandwidth between the client and the server is not a bottleneck, **and** your server supports parallel process, **then** you can create multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it doesn't matter as long as you do it properly.

It easier to do properly with a background worker so i'd suggest doing it with that.